# Prebid.js + GAM

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I have an adapter for prebid and it works itself. But when I try to use it with GAM - get errors: "no creative id" and "no campain id".
The adapter returns all the necessary fields, like creativeAd, adId, ad, adUrl and others.
The HB endpoint also returns the result.
Why can't I see the ads? Have anyone faced with such issue?

If it needs some extract information, I'll update the question.

I just copied the code from the prebid site and changed adUnits and slot ids.

P.S. Timeout was increased up to 5000. No  changes.

Comment: did you create the prebid line items in GAM ?

Comment: yes, I did. I've just noticed, it saved with status "draft". can this be the cause? if yes, how to fix it? I've tried to activate, but with no success.

Comment: so you dont have the right to activate de campaign ? try to ask the GAM admin to do so and check if it solves the problem..

Comment: ok, activated. but still no ads displayed

Comment: could you share a test page?

Comment: One of the examples: [test1](https://staging.newsochub.com/test1.html?pbjs=debug&googfc)

Comment: I do see a creative being displayed in your adslot and it looks like bids are requested the proper way. you sure you don't have any adblocking plugin turned on ?

Comment: I don't use any ad block tools. Tested in different browsers. And I'm not the only who don't see ads.

Comment: here is the line item id that i see with the googletag console : 6244359967. Could you check in the GAM user interface if there are country targetings or other targetings that could explain why i see it and you don't ?

Comment: @rabsom. Wow, that's a magic!!! Definitely - magic. I see ads. Nothing has changed in settings after line item activating. It was a few days ago.

Comment: glad it works ;) maybe your browser cache (consent strings, bad adscript setup in memory...)?

Comment: sorry, but again no. that was test creative from gam. creative from HB don't display.

Comment: I have stuck while using prebid.js with samples, and i see that you have done with your problem, could you please share some links or some github repo to take a look on it and check your implementation if it's possible, i would really appreciate that!